# Autocomplete command from a certain folder

Tags: bash, scripting, autocomplete

I'm trying to write a bash script that autocompletes folder names from a certain folder. This is what I have so far:

```bsh
function go {
  cd "/path/to/folder/$@"
}
```

The goal is to have the function autocomplete, so typing `go pro` and pressing tab would autocomplete to a file or folder, for example `/path/to/folder/project/`

Comment: What is in your environment that this doesn't already happen?

Comment: @NasirRiley I think OP wants the auto-complete to apply to the command referenced inside the `go` function (i.e. the `cd` with the hard-coded `/path/to/folder` prefix), not the "simple start-from-here"  type of autocompletion ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `complete` you can achive what you want:

---

Add to your `.bashrc`:

```bsh
if [[ -f /path/to/your/script ]]; then
  . /path/to/your/script
fi
```

Then run, from your home directory:

```
. .bashrc
```

Create the script `/path/to/your/script`, make it executable `chmod +x /path/to/your/script`. Put this content:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# check that the function doesn't already exist
[[ ! -z "$(compgen -c | grep "^go$")" ]] \
  && echo "The command 'go' already exists." \
  && exit

go() {
 cd /your/dir/"$1"
}

cd_my_dir() {
 cd /your/dir
}

complete -d -F cd_my_dir go
```

---

**Type** `go` and **press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice**

```
go <Tab> <Tab>
```

A list of possible directories will appear:

```
foo/
bar/
```

Start to type the beginning of a name, it will auto-complete:

```
go f <Tab> → go foo/
```

Comment: This works well, but could you also tell me how to put this script into the .bashrc file itself? That's where I usually put the binds I use for workflow. Or is that a bad idea?

Comment: Also, it seems to require multiple letters once inside the directory, e.g.:
```go project```
```go p <Tab> (nothing) <Tab>```
```project/```
ideally, it would always use a single tab to autocomplete folder names, even when inside the target directory

Comment: @Iaotle I could't get just one tab press, sorry, I tried. About putting the code in `.bashrc`, I'm not sure it would be a problem. But I prefer, to have things clean and controlled, to put my scripts in other files and just source them from `.bashrc`. If you have to edit the code it's much easier to edit a specific script. If you don't want it anymore, just delete a few lines in `.bashrc`, you don't have to navigate all the code there.